# Displaying image with php cache vs directory read

Tags: php, image, symfony, caching

I use Intervention/Image with Symfony 3
I am saving the pictures uploaded to the system after they improve.

**Schema**

Image -> Upload -> Resize(1440x960) -> Watermark -> Save(Filesystem) -> Done..

*I need a 200x200 thumbnail.
Which one should I use for thumbnail creation and why?

1. Image -> Resize(200x200) -> Save(Filesystem) -> Show(Url - Not Php) //Resize and save the image.
2. Php -> Image(Read Intervention/Image) -> Resize(200x200) -> Show(Php - Intervention/Imagecache)
   Using : http://image.intervention.io/use/cache

There is no flexibility in the first method. But it can be fast. It needs to be re-created for different sizes.

The second method is flexible. Auto cached files are created for different sizes. It may not be fast. Do you load the server because you use php? etc..

What do you guys think about this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm moving all the assets to a cdn to prevent that extra load to my server. Until now I have been using Varnish to cache images and serve them directly from memory and avoid disk I/O . The difference is notable between disk, varnish and cdn.

Some kind of proxy cache can be a good choice to improve the performance without too much complication.